# Is it legal to import software(Game) from the US to India, which is not for sale in India?

Tags: grand-theft-auto-v, legal

I am a big fan of GTA (Grand Theft Auto) and I am a PC gamer waiting for GTA V PC version for months now.

I have seen that it will be available on Jan 27th on amazon.com and we can pre-order it.

As I stay in India I asked my sister to buy that game for me (she lives in the USA). Now my question is: Is it legal to carry the DVD with her when she comes to India?

Comment: Do you mean that it's banned, or that it's got a later release date? I looked it up and couldn't find any reference online to it being banned.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because legal questions are off-topic here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the research I have seen, there should be no problem bringing over a disc with a game on it to another country (in your case, India). There is, however, some rule that restricts people to only bringing one piece of *hardware* over at a time (computer, console, etc.) but it shouldn't affect you.